# Why is the body not starting from the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a fixed navbar and then make a grid container underneath it, but the problem is that my body is starting under the navbar.
When I change my navbar position to anything other than "fixed" it works, but I do want it fixed at the top of the page, so How can I make the body start from the top of the page?

Here is where the body is at:

[image]

HTML code:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar">

  <div class="navbar-website-icon">
    <img src="website-icon.jpg" alt="" height="55%" width="65%">
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-about">
    <p>About</p>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-the-grid">
    <p>The Grid</p>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-how-the-grid-works">
    <p>How The Grid Works</p>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-customer-industry">
    <p>Customer & Industry</p>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-library">
    <p>Library</p>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-newsroom">
    <p>Newsroom</p>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-contact">
    <p>Contact</p>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-search-icon">
    <img src="search-icon.jpg" alt="" height="25%" width="30%">
  </div>

</nav>


<!-- Grid container -->

<div class="grid-container">

  <header>
    <h1 class="projects-div-h1">Projects</h1>
    <p class="projects-div-p">On this page, you can find out about current and recent projects for grid development.</p>
  </header>

</div>
```

CSS code:

```
body{
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.navbar{
  /* outline: black solid thin; */
  width: 75%;
  height: 6.3rem;
  left: auto;
  right: 15%;
  top:0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: fixed;
}

.grid-container{
  margin-top: 6.3rem;
  display: grid;
  outline: green solid thin;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8,12.5%);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,25%);
}
```

Comment: The inspector tooltip is misleading you... Try to apply a `border: 3px solid red;` on the body... You will se the it starts at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace styles `.navbar` and `.grid-container` with these. You will get the same visual result but without the problem that worries you

```
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 6.3rem;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: sticky;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    outline: green solid thin;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 12.5%);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
}
```